Script pulls specific file number from zip folder gmail attachement into gsheets, but file number keeps changing order with each new email
After two solid days of searching for answers, I've decided to ask! ;)
I've pieced together a script from various 'stack overflow' sources that will pull a specific csv file from a multi-file zipped attachment from gmail into gsheets daily.
Issues:

An email is received each day with an attached zipped folder containing 12 csv files. In the script I have pieced together, with the help of this community, I have it set to pull the 11th file in the zipped folder. Even though visually the zipped files remain in the same order each new day, the numbered order of the file seems to change. Example, running the script yesterday for the 11th file in the zip returned the 4th file.  Running the script today for the 11th file in the zip returned the 2nd file. Again when looking at the attachments visually after unzipping the folder they remain in the same alphabetical order every day.

I have tried to use the name of the specific csv file. The file name in the zipped folder is called 'Open_Positions' but the date is attached to each new day so exact file name changes daily. For example yesterday's file name was, 'Open_Positions_2024_04_09.csv'


Any ideas what I can do aside from creating a script the requires me to run it 12 different times so as to collect all 12 zipped files each on their own tab?
Here is a copy of the script. Issue occurs in 'Step 4: PARSE CSV DATA'.
function NewBNP() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RawBNP'), true);
var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('A1')
var cellContent = cell.getValue()

if(cellContent === 'RUN') 


{

//Step1: GET MOST RECENT MESSAGE BY LABEL
var threads = GmailApp.search("Standard - CFL REP001");
var message = threads[0].getMessages();
message = message[message.length - 1];
var attachments = message.getAttachments();

Logger.log("Message Found");
var attachments = message.getAttachments();
for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
var attachment = attachments[i];
}
Logger.log("Attachement Stored");


//Step 2: FIND SPREADHSEET
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById ("16xx4y899tRWNfCZIARw4wDmuqUcMtjB2ZZlznjaeaUc");
Logger.log("Sheet Opened");

//Step 3: FIND SHEET INSIDE SPREADHSEET
var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("RawBNP");
Logger.log("Tab Found");


//Step 4: PARSE CSV DATA
var blobs = Utilities.unzip(attachment.setContentType(MimeType.ZIP)); 
if (blobs.length <= 1) {
throw new Error("Multiple files cannot be found.");
}
var csvFileOf11thFile = blobs[11];

var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFileOf11thFile.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");
Logger.log("CSV data loaded");


//Step 5: SINSERT DATA AKA .getRange(row, column, lastrow based on CSV data);
sheetName.getRange(3, 2, csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
Logger.log("Data pasted");


}
}

